# Где хранить service worker?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pwa, service-worker

Загорелся идеей добавить service worker при помощи workbox в существующий проект на WordPress, но столкнулся с одной проблемой: где его расположить и как зарегистрировать чтобы он кэшировал не только js и css файлы из папки dist в папке темы, но ещё и изображения товаров (разумеется с лимитом на их количество) ?

Comment: Один вопрос, зачем вордпресс? Это представляете, сколько ему кешировать придется, если это вообще возможно pwa и вордпресс

Comment: @RavenTheX нет никаких проблем реализовать PWA на ВП. Вообще нет. Строго говоря PWA вообще не зависит от движка.

Comment: Быстро и просто: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/pwa. Долго и обстоятельно можно начинать отсюда https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps В частности про service worker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API